# Security essentials not starting

Tags: anti-virus, malware, ms-security-essentials, anti-spyware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

When I attempt to navigate to a site using IE I am always redirected to a seemingly random internet site. When open security essentials it pops up briefly before disappearing.
So im unable to run scans.

I've tried anti-malware (malwarebyte) and it has quarantined some items but same issue remains. What else can I try ?

Comment: Yikes.  Time to abandon ship. Grab the backups and reformat, because only God knows what else is on your machine now.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try scanning with Windows defender offline. It's available on [Windows Update](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/what-is-windows-defender-offline)

Answer (score 0):

Just start your computer in [safe mode](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/boot_failsafe.mspx?mfr=true), this way it won't shut down the process so that you can scan.